# What type of superconductors does Maglev train use and why?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, superconductivity

I would like to find out what type of superconductors does the Maglev train use and why is this is this specific type? As I cannot find it anywhere on the net. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not all MAGLEV trains use superconductors. SCMAGLEV (Superconducting Maglev) in Japan uses a niobium-titanium alloy cooled with liquid helium (https://www.scmaglev.com/). "superior high-critical-magnetic-field, high-critical-supercurrent-density properties of Nb-Ti ..., together with affordability and easy workability, distinguish Nb-Ti alloys from thousands of other superconductors and justify their status as the most widely utilized (workhorse) superconductors." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niobium-titanium)